# Azure Application Gateway - Prevent redirection

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, web-application-firewall

I've a AppService running with an endpoint www.test.com.   I've deployed an Application Geteway and set up a backend pool to forward traffic from AG to www.test.com.    I've then created DNS records to point www.test.org to the AG IP.   When I navigate to www.test.org the browser does a 301 redirect to www.test.com.

I want to prevent the redirection as from the users point of view, however I want the request to forward www.test.com but the browser to remain the same.

Interesting I had previously done this on another site with the exact same config (I think) with the only exception it is using the tier WAF2.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTTPSettings, update the Override Hostname field with "www.test.com". When you do that the actual request will be for "www.test.org" and when the request goes to your backend pool, it will have "www.test.com" as the hostname.

This should fix your issue. You don't need to configure any redirect in your backend server.